# Adding CoCosDenshion to exsiting project

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to add CoCosDenshion to an existing project I've created but I'm getting the following error within CocosDenshion.m file

```
"CCFileUtils.h" file not found
```

When I find this file and add it I get more linker errors.

I've added this using 2 tutorials that both suggest the same thing.

I'm using cocos2d-iphone folder to extract it.

I'm also supporting arm (-fno-objc-arc) & adding necessary libraries (AudioToolbox.framework, OpenAL.framework, AVFoundation.framework).

Can anyone help me out here, can tell where I'm going wrong? (Spent about 2 days trying to add CocosDenshion to my project..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `CocosDenshion` does not support of ARC so far. You have you specify not to compile your `cocosDenshion` files via ARC. For this go to Targets->Build Phases->Compiles Sources then find the specific file you want to remove ARC from it, once you find that file double click on it and add `-fno-objc-arc` as flag.

Comment: I've done that but it's complaining that loads of files are missing.